# How to call have access to dbContext in a class without adding dbContext as a argument to the class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the `ValuesController`, I'm calling method `GetUsers` of a class `TestRepo` to get list of all the users from the database. To do that I had to pass in the `_context` to `TestRepo()` like

```
var testRepo = new TestRepo(_context);
return testRepo.GetUsers();
```

How do I avoid passing `_context` to class `TestRepo`. Ideally, I want `_context` to be available to me in `TestRepo` and I don't want to pass `_context` in `TestRepo`. What is the right way of doing this?

***ValuesController.cs***

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDBContext _context;

    public ValuesController(ApplicationDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        var testRepo = new TestRepo(_context);
        return testRepo.GetUsers();
    }
}
```

***TestRepo.cs***

```
public class TestRepo
{
    private readonly ApplicationDBContext _context;

    public TestRepo(ApplicationDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _context.Users.ToList(); ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass TestRepo to controller constructor... Or better... Use interface and DI

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve by not passing it as a constructor argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection). .NET supports the dependency injection (DI) software design pattern, which is a technique for achieving Inversion of Control (IoC) between classes and their dependencies. Dependency injection in .NET is a built-in part of the framework, along with configuration, logging, and the options pattern.

A dependency is an object that another object depends on.

When you register your `DbContext` in the app you add it to the DI-container and then your controller can resolve a new instance of `ApplicationDBContext` for you. But you can add other dependencies to the DI-container and inject it as a dependency via constructor parameter.

For example in your case if you use Startup.cs you can add `TestRepo` as [scoped dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // you already has this 2 lines of code somewhere
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddControllers();

    // use AddScoped to add TestRepo to DI-container
    services.AddScoped<TestRepo>();
    
}
```

or if you use modern style application builder use next syntax:

```
// you already has this 2 lines of code somewhere
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// use AddScoped to add TestRepo to DI-container
builder.Services.AddScoped<TestRepo>();
```

After registering the `DbContext` and the `TestRepo` class in container, you can use the `TestRepo` in the `ValuesController` to get an instance `TestRepo` class with injected `DbContext`:

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private TestRepo _testRepo;
    public ValuesController(TestRepo testRepo)
    {
        _testRepo = testRepo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        return _testRepo.GetUsers();
    }
}
```

Also you can [inject your dependency directly to the action method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#action-injection-with-fromservices) with `FromServices` attribute:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Get([FromServices] TestRepo testRepo)
{
    return testRepo.GetUsers();
}
```

Note that dependency injection is related to interfaces and abstractions, so it is important to use it when you use DI. It's a part of SOLID principles. Interfaces provide a level of abstraction from the concrete implementation, making it easier to swap out implementations and allowing for greater flexibility and reusability and easier testing with mocks.

Finally understanding the life cycle of dependency injection is very important in ASP.Net (Core) applications. Transient objects are always different; a new instance is provided to every controller and every service. Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests. Singleton objects are the same for every object and every request. You can learn more in .net [tutorial "Use dependency injection in .NET"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage).